# Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree - GetX Navigation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am using GetX plugin to navigate between the pages. And when I navigate back to the page which has Text input field I get '*Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree*'

**Main Page**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/binding.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/next.dart';
import 'package:flutter_easyloading/flutter_easyloading.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Kids Game',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const HomePage(),
      initialBinding: HomeBinding(),
      builder: EasyLoading.init(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: TextFormField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                autocorrect: false,
                controller: controller.editCtrl,
              )),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Get.to(() => NextPage())
            },
            child: Text("Next"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**NextPage Widget**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/main.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class NextPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final homeCtrl = Get.find<HomeController>();
  NextPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("this is next page"),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Get.offAll(() => HomePage(), transition: Transition.downToUp);
              },
              child: const Text("Go Back"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Controller.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController {
  //GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final editCtrl = TextEditingController();
}
```

**Binding**

```
import 'package:flutter_application_1/controller.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class HomeBinding implements Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(
      () => HomeController(),
    );
  }
}
```

When I navigate to NextPage, and then back to HomePage I get the error

> Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.

I read a few different posts, and people had recommended using static with *formkey* as that has resolved the issue for them so I tried doing the same but it didn't work for me.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 4):

The issue got resolved. I did the following, in case someone else is facing the issue. I declared the key as private and change the variable from final.

```
GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

And based on a lot of answers I have read, the key is for UI layer so it shouldn't be declared in the controller.

Comment: are you still able to have `const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);` with that?  i am only able to use this without const constructor for my screen's widget class (HomePage in this case).

Answer (score 2):

When leaving the page with **Getx** use one of these options, depending on your routing solution:

```dart
Get.offAndToNamed('next_screen')
```

or

```dart
Get.off(NextScreen());
```

This removes the current page from the navigation stack and thus the error `Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree` should be gone for good when reentering the page.

Source:

https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/route_management.md

Comment: i'm using await Get.offAndToNamed('myScreen'); but it doesn't change the result for me on this problem. any other ideas? my code is structured similarly as OP's, except that i'm using GetBuilder in my screen widget.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the form key for each widget. Forexample: Just use `globalFormKey1` for the first widget and `GlobalFormKey2` for the second one. This will not give the error of duplications.

Comment: second widget doesn’t have any form

Answer (score 1):

I had issue similar to that navigation worked fine, but when I run web and save changes I got exception saying that there is a duplicate key new child use the same global key , I solve this by  :

```
 //replace
 Get.to(Register())
 
 //with
 Get.toNamed('/register')
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the static and final type from the key variable so if

static final GlobalKey _abcKey = GlobalKey();

change it to

GlobalKey _abcKey = GlobalKey();

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use the widget as a continuation:

```
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

because when you navigate from one page to another, the GloblaKey is not permanently deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to `Get.to(const PageSelectMyInfo());`.
it redirects to /PageSelectMyInfo which is wrong route name.

So I changed it to `Get.toNamed('select-my-info');` it works.

Answer (score 0):

on the line

```
  static final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

remote the "static final"